# What should I install with Qt 5.5.1 for C++ GUI?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I want to install QT for `C++` but I don't know what to install. So, I googled it and found this site [Qt.io](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) but now I don't know what to download. I've download the online installer for windows. And again I've to choose what to install with it.

**So, can any one help with that?**

*Guys Is it possible to install it in offline mode?

Here is from which I should choose.
[image: Here is from which I should choose.]*

Comment: Install Qt 5.5 + Tools. From Qt 5.5 install modules that you will need, there is a description of every component when you click on it (or you can find it in the docs on qt.io).

Comment: The installer has clearly selected the "default" option for you (as it's greyed out in the UI = already selected); why don't you try that first and _if_ something doesn't work, then ask?

Comment: Too many questions. Try reading the manual instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the default options at first, it'll give you a full development environment with the Qt-based tools (Creator, Designer etc) which when you get started are almost essential whilst you learn Qt. There's an offline installer as well, in the Downloads section there's an Online Installer section, below is an Offline Installer section.

Comment: is there a faster site to download those files?

Comment: BTW offline installer contain all modules, but online installer will only download what you selected. So, using online installer is faster.

Comment: but the offline installer is only 1 gb and the online installer by default ask us to install 5.98 gb. why is that? @vladon

Comment: Offline installed will have the same disc space requirement, but the files are compressed down to make it easier to distribute.

Comment: @AnishSilwal because 5.98 gb is *after* unpacking :-)

Comment: @ASK moreover, installer will download only those small compressed files which you selected